# h5py assigning to dataset my multidimensional index

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, hdf5, h5py

Using h5py I have a hdf5 dataset D of shape (n_1, …, n_k, m) and I want to write vectors of length m (for example) at index i=(i_1, …, i_k) where k is completely arbitrary

If I knew k in advance I could write

```
D[i_1, ..., i_k] = vector
```

How can I do this in a more arbitrary way? What I really would really like (which is invalid python) would be something that could be understood using the parameter expansion operator (that can't actually be used here)

```
D[*i] = vector
```

Comment: With numpy arrays, `D[atuple]` is valid multidimensional indexing.  I expect the same applies to a `h5py` dataset, but haven't tried it.  Elements of that tuple can be `slice` objects as well as integers or lists/arrays.  http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Comment: Hi I thought that at first, but it actually applies the tuple to multiple indexes along the same dimension and complains that my indexes are not in order

Comment: Actually no you are correct. If I change my index from a list to a tuple it works! Strange that lists and tuples behave differently here, but thanks. If you want to make an answer out of this I'll accept it.

Comment: Lists and tuples behavior differently in all of `numpy` indexing.  Current versions have tightened up some loopholes inherited from the past.